# C# using hook to bypass the new libvlc api

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, libvlc

I am using vlc to capture a video and audio stream and display it in a picture box. The new libvlc api no longer supports the double click/fullscreen  in windows and I need to have that functionality. I don't have a problem creating a new form, adding a picture box to it and showing the video in that, but I do have a problem capturing the double click event in the vlc window in order to tell the app to make the video feed fullscreen. I found out that I need to use a hook. I have the hook installed and all of that. My only problem is, I only want to handle the message if it is a click in one of my pictureboxes. So, from my callback method, here is what I need:

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 &&  MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            //Here I need to grab the Handle of the control that the mouse was clicked in.
            //Now I need to cast the Control.FromHandle() as PictureBox.
            // then if(control != null)
            // send the event to the form via. form.on_double_click or whatever.


        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Any ideas?

**Ubdate**:

Here is what I've got now, look good?

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 &&  MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT msg = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT));

            PictureBox control = Control.FromHandle(msg.hwnd) as PictureBox;

            if (control != null)
            {
                PreviewForm.pbox_MouseDoubleClick(control, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 2, msg.pt.x, msg.pt.y, 0));
            }                
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

**Update**

Another little gotcha for those coming in from Google. In Windows 7, If you attach your debugger to the callback, it will appear to be broken. There is a timeout value on hook responses, if that timeout ever expires, your hook will never fire again for the life of the hook. From my reading, it appears that this is a Windows 7 issue while it works on Windows Vista and less. The break point in your debugger will most certainly force this timeout to expire and as a result, your callback will only be called once. However, it will work fine without the break point.

Comment: Have you tried to catch the double-click event in your `picture box`?

Comment: @L.B. Yes, I do not get the event once vlc is using the control. I tried turning off the vlc mouse events, but it still doesn't pass the event up the chain.

Comment: I faced with the same problem while ago, but I don't remember how I solved it. For example, put another control on top of your control and attach to double-click event of it.

Comment: @L.B I figured I might be able to do something like that, but a. vlc recommends the hook approach. b. The picture boxes are bound dynamically and I don't want to rewrite the code.

Comment: @L.B This approach doesn't work since in .NET you cannot do a global hook with WH_MOUSE which is the one I need if I am going to sort the handles. I'd love more info on your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lParam` is a pointer to a [MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which will contain the window handle.

You can use the definition a [Pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT.html) and marshal lParam to that type.

Comment: the msg.hwnd value is always 0, in the code I posted above. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using the WH_MOUSE hook correct?  What are you using for the definition of the POINT structure?  Are any of the other field set correctly in the msg structure?

Comment: Yes, the Point is correct. Since this is a separate question, I started a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054287/c-sharp-hook-hwnd-is-always-0

Comment: Thanks!, you had know way of knowing that I had used the wrong hook. Thank you for your help.